# How to detect if a player has touched a block with hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you can make a scoreboard to detect if a player mined a block, But I don't know how to make something to detect if a player touches a block(not break the block). I'm on java edition 1.18.

Comment: What do you mean "touches" a block, do you mean stepped on it or left-clicked on it?

Comment: I mean left-click on the block.